# Unexpected round behavior

Tags: r, rounding

When I type
`round(1122700.625, 2)`
I get 1122701

when I would expect 1122700.62 from my reading of ?round (nearest even)

Somewhat similarly for
`round(205290.125, 2)`
I get 205280.1

when I would expect 205290.12

`round(205290.125,3)` and `round(205290.125,4)` both give 205290.1

round(2.125, 2) gives 2.12 as expected

and

`round(22222.125, 2)` gives 22222.12 as expected

but `round(222222.125, 2)` gives 222222.1

and `round(2222222.125, 2)` gives 2222222

I have tried running R from the command line with --vanilla option with the same result (originally noted when using RStudio).

The help does also state "The realities of computer arithmetic can cause unexpected results" but

Am I missing something/what don't I understand?

Does this matter?!

Comment: What does `getOption("digits")` give you?

Comment: I believe this is purely a display issue: `round(205290.125, 2)` _is_ giving (a value very close to) `205290.12`, but then it's rounding that value to 7 significant figures for display. Try doing `round(205290.125, 2) - 205290` and you should see a result that's close to `0.12`, not to `0.1`.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you looking for toFixed because the round only expect one param.

[CLICK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for ref.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but I believe you made a mistake. It may be true for Javascript. `Math.round`does indeed accept only a floating point number that is rounded to the nearest integer.  But the question is about R and in R round does accept a second argument ([doc here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Round)).